# Fail to run stored procedure using DataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am new to ADO.net. I have student table with ID, Name and Address as columns. ID is primary key and set to auto increment. I have written below stored procedure

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertStudent]
  @_Name nvarchar(15),
  @_address nvarchar(45)
AS
INSERT INTO Student (Name, Address) VALUES(@_Name, @_address);

Go.
```

To run this stored procedure I have written below method

```
private static void RunStoredProcedure()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=server_name;initial      catalog=TestDB;trusted_connection=true"))
    {

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Student", connection);

        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("InsertStudent", connection);
        adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@_Name", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "Name").Value = "John";
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@_address", SqlDbType.NChar, 45, "Address").Value = "Paris";

        DataTable students = new DataTable();

        adapter.Fill(students);

        adapter.Update(students);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately no row gets inserted after running this method.
If I run similar code using ExcecuteNonQuery() it works fine. Please help me to solve the issue as I want to use DataAdapter's Update() method only.

Comment: No need of connection.Open(); while using SqlDataAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@_Name", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "Name").Value = "John";
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@_address", SqlDbType.NChar, 45, "Address").Value = "Paris";
```

you have to *add a new row to your DataTable* prior to calling the Update function of the SqlDataAdapter:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SO;trusted_connection=true"))
{
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Student", connection);

   adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("InsertStudent", connection);
   adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@_Name", SqlDbType.NChar, 15, "Name");
   adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@_address", SqlDbType.NChar, 45, "Address");

   DataTable students = new DataTable();

   adapter.Fill(students);

   // Add a new row.
   DataRow sRow = students.NewRow();
   sRow["Name"] = "John";
   sRow["Address"] = "Paris";
   students.Rows.Add(sRow);

   adapter.Update(students);
 }
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99(v=vs.110).aspx) for a working example of what you are trying to do.

Once the Update method is invoked, the SQL data adapter object executes the SQL INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands (as specified by the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and DeleteCommand properties) to **persist DataTable changes to the database**.

Thus, if a *new row* has been added to the DataTable, then the corresponding SQL INSERT command is executed. In this case the insert command is a sproc. All DataTable fields are mapped to the corresponding sproc parameters and subsequently the sproc is executed. You end up with a new row added in your DB Table.

Comment: Your suggestion is worked. Thanks lot!! But I am confused because Stored procedure already have Insert query. Then why I need to add new row explicitly. Please explain me.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos!! Your explanation has cleared by doubt.